# Routes in Laravel with parameters in URL

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I would like to implement a route that accepts email and a reference id

```
email: test@email.com
ref_id: abcd1234

website.com/ticket/email=test@email.com1&ref_id=abcd1234
```

how do I design this url in laravel? should I just use a get route?

Comment: A GET route could work.

Comment: Use a GET, but how its constructed depends on whether you would allow altered values.

Comment: Please review my answer, it will help you to understand the routing of laravel. Please accept my answer if that really helpful to you to understand the routing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('ticket/{email}/{ref_id}', 'YourController@YourMethod');
```

Please visit [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) for more details about routes.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

```
Route::get('ticket/email={email}/ref_id={ref_id}', 'YourController@metodName');
```

Comment: @nyelnyelnyelnyelnyel: Thanks for upvote. Feel free to accept this as answer if our solution addressed your concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/ticket/{email}/{id}', function(){
    // You controller code goes here
}
```

Or if you are using seperate controller for each model

```
Route::get('/ticket/{email}/{id}', 'TicketController@method_name');
```